# How to add Details field for Custom option in magento admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, custom, fieldsets

[image]For the custom options of simple prodcusts i have to add one text field for value of color. How to add it.

Comment: Please follow my link might be useful for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159833/custom-options-drop-down-add-field/159854#159854

Comment: if it useful for you please vote for the answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the SKU as the hex code and then sniff for it on the frontend, adding some template logic to the `catalog/product/view/options.phtml` instead of adding a new column and text option attribute.

This may not be considered the "correct" approach - there are certainly better ways to address this - but it may be the easiest in your case with the requirement of using options.

Comment: We have only require to add it as Details field.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this solution [add-custom attributes custom options](http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-attributes-custom-options)

Comment: Please always add all necessary informations to the post, in case if the link dies. The tutorial is ok, but it missed important informations.