# Custom Options - Drop Down add field

Tags: custom-options

I have 2000+ products all set to simple products but with custom options.

An option is a drop-down option with an SKU etc... What I want to know is, is it possible to add another input box after 'Sort Order' to say 'stock count'??

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.2

[image: Current Custom Options]

Comment: version please and could you share me any screenshot where you exact want to add?

Comment: you want to add it as order attribute or product attribute ?

Comment: @NAGARAJUK I've added this.

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar product option.

Comment: Sure I will help you.

Comment: @NAGARAJUK ok great.

Comment: please try this in the default magento (local) confirm me whether it is working or not. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

**Step1:**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php
```

you have to modify the code in the line numbers 263 and 287 (or) search `sku` as keyword, based on that just keep below code.

line number 263

```
 'stockcount' => $_value->getStockcount(),
```

and in the line number 287

```
$value['stockcount'] = $option->getStockcount();
```

[image]

[image]

**Step 2:**

```
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/select.phtml
```

line number 42 add below code

```
'<th class="type-stockcount"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsQuoteEscape(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Stock Count')) ?></th>'+
```

line number 67

```
+'<td><input type="text" class="validate-zero-or-greater input-text" name="product[options][{{id}}][values][{{select_id}}][stockcount]" value="{{stockcount}}"></td>'+
```

**step 3:**

finally you should add create a column '**stockcount**' in the database table called **catalog_product_option_type_value** as shown in the below screenshot

[image]

Finally **clear cache and session**

**output:**

[image: corrected the links]

Comment: You should never modify core code! Extend the classes instead. And do not extend the database table directly, always use setup scripts!

Comment: yes i will follow @Black thanks for your suggestion