# Custom option with a drop down when input type selected is a drop down.?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, product-attribute, custom-options

How to add a new drop down beside "Price Type" present in custom options of Product Information.

[image: See Image for detail]

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/159854/20064

Comment: That is for a text box, i need to add a drop down(Select Option) with shipping fields in it ? just like Price Type .

Answer (score 0):

So here how i did it .. may be it can help someone too.

**Step 1**

open

```
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/select.phtml
```

First we need to create a html select option

As i needed to show the shipping options , i have created the select option using my own
So open the file and add the code at the top.

`$shipping = array(
  array(
    'value' => 'UPS',
    'label' => 'UPS',
  ),
  array(
    'value' => 'DHL',
    'label' => 'DHL',
  ),
  array(
   'value' => 'Spedition',
   'label' => 'Spedition'
  ),
    array(
   'value' => 'Hermes',
   'label' => 'Hermes'
  ),
);
$select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select');
$select->setOptions($shipping);
$select->setName('product[options][{{id}}][values][{{select_id}}][title]')
->setClass('required-entry input-text select-type-title {{title}}')
->setId('product_option_{{id}}select{{select_id}}_title')`

here as i don't need the title option i replaced that field name with my new select option .

Then for the variable OptionTemplateSelectRow add the select option

```
   +'<?php echo $select->getHtml();?>{{checkboxScopeTitle}}</td>'+
```

After you can be able to see the select option in place of title.

Now for the selectOptionType script variable in the "add" name option add the below code after 
 
         `if (data.price_type) {
          }`

```
Add the below code:

if (data.title) {
             $A($('product_option_'+data.id+'_select_'+data.select_id+'_title').options).each(function(option){
            if (option.value==data.title) option.selected = true;
        });
    }
```